# Is there a way to do a shared notebook other than OneNote?

Tags: 2007, third-party-software

I need to implement a Shared Notebook in Sharepoint, and am looking for ways to do it other than Microsoft OneNote (nothing against it, just want to explore options).

Anything out there?

**EDIT:**  I'm looking for an application that will allow me to make timestamped notes, and allow others to modify it (with mod history).  These notes will document our daily activities, so there will be many of them.  There doesn't need to be any hyperlinking between them, they just need to be text and date searchable.  It would be nice to go to a certain time, and then page back and forth in case search words aren't remembered or intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a great way to use regular SharePoint lists with versioning turned on.  It is really easy to use it for keeping a task journal.

Comment: Lance, considering your comments to Muhimbi, I agree with Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a SharePoint Wiki or do you need simultaneous editing of the same page?

Comment: I don't need simultaneous editing, and Wiki doesn't sound like the right solution.  It's more of a completed-task-tracker with details, so often I won't need to edit it.  See my Edit above.

Answer (score 0):

What functionality are you looking for? A wiki might be OK though OneNote is certainly provides for richer layout (ie. it's not bound by HTML display rules).

If you don't mind having your data outside SharePoint, perhaps EverNote might fit the bill.

Comment: See edit and comment on other question.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it is worth, I would avoid putting too much time into implementing something custom or third party unless you have a really big business need and you are extremely unlikely to upgrade to 2010 in the near future.  Office and SharePoint 2010 provide the ability for "co-authoring" which will let multiple people work with both Excel and Word Documents at the same time for real-time collaboration.

Comment: We're actually going to test out OneNote this week, I just wanted to see what options there were.